# Having an issue with a JS scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me a bit with an issue I'm having. Unfortunately, I'm not super experienced with JS so I'm having some trouble.

I have a site that has a full page background image. When the user scrolls, the background image changes. I got this solution from another post here on Stack Overflow a while ago but I can't seem to find that post anywhere to save my life otherwise that's where I'd be posting this.

In any case, there is a code snippet below. The three issues I'm having are:

1. Currently, when it gets to the last image, it stops, unless the user scrolls back up. What I'd like it to do is when the person gets to the last image, I'd like it to restart from the beginning so it'll just be looping as the user keeps scrolling down.
2. On Firefox, when it gets to the last image, the user can't even scroll back upwards to go back to the previous images. It just gets to the last one and stops, period.
3. It doesn't work on iPhone. Obviously, I know that's because iPhone is touch and this JS is looking for mousewheel, but is there a specific JS code I can use to target touch?

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

P.S. On Windows, it recognizes a full wheel scroll as one scroll which is great but on Mac, a full scroll will cycle through all images at once. Is that just a Mac thing because it's very annoying?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 1;
  var maxIndex = $('.content').length;
  var endAnim = true;
  $('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    if (endAnim) {
      if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 90 > 0) {
        if (index > 1) {
          endAnim = false;
          index--;
          $('.content-' + (index)).addClass('main-content').fadeIn(500);
          $('.content-' + (index + 1)).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('main-content');
            endAnim = true;
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (index < maxIndex) {
          endAnim = false;
          index++;
          $('.content-' + (index)).addClass('main-content').fadeIn(500);
          $('.content-' + (index - 1)).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('main-content');
            endAnim = true;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.main-content {
 top: 0 !important;
 z-index: 100 !important;
}
.pageContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 background: white;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-1 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/f88WDy/test_image_1.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-2 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/fbVNLd/test_image_2.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-3 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/i79Gfd/test_image_3.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="content content-1 main-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum One</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Two</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Three</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use modular arithmetic. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 1;
  $('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    $('.content-' + index).removeClass('main-content');
    index = index%3 + 1;
    $('.content-' + index).addClass('main-content');
  });
});
```

```css
.main-content {
 top: 0 !important;
 z-index: 100 !important;
}
.pageContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 background: white;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-1 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/f88WDy/test_image_1.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-2 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/fbVNLd/test_image_2.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-3 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/i79Gfd/test_image_3.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="content content-1 main-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum One</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Two</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Three</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EXTENDED ANSWER**
I am at university right now so i will fully explain this later.
I created a hiddenScroll that contains an element of size 3x the size of the screen.
I then changed the scroll position of hiddenScroll to 1x the size of the screen so that when the scrollTop becomes 0, the scroll event triggers the second if or that when the scrollTop becomes 3x the size of the screen it triggers the first if.

You are actually scrolling a scrollbar from a transparent div (hence hidden div).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 1;
  $(".hiddenScroll").scrollTop($( document ).height())
  $('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    
    var hiddenScrollbar = $(".hiddenScroll");
    if(hiddenScrollbar.scrollTop() == 2*$( document ).height()){
    
      $('.content-' + index).removeClass('main-content');
      index = index%3 + 1;
      $('.content-' + index).addClass('main-content');
      hiddenScrollbar.scrollTop($( document ).height());
      
    }else if($(".hiddenScroll").scrollTop() == 0){
    
      $('.content-' + index).removeClass('main-content');
      index = index == 1 ? 3 : index - 1;
      $('.content-' + index).addClass('main-content');
      hiddenScrollbar.scrollTop($( document ).height());
    
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.main-content {
 top: 0 !important;
 z-index: 100 !important;
}
.pageContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 background: white;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-1 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/f88WDy/test_image_1.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-2 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/fbVNLd/test_image_2.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.content-3 {
 background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/i79Gfd/test_image_3.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.hiddenScroll {
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  filter: opacity(0);
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="content content-1 main-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum One</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Two</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content content-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Three</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenScroll">
    <div style="height: 300vh;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Your solution actually works great on all browsers but it doesn't treat a normal swipe of the scroll wheel as one scroll. So, for example, if I roll the scroll wheel like I normally would on a page, it cycles through all images like three times. Would you know how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: Do you have any advice as to how I would go about fixing the scroll issue? I'd like it to treat each full scroll of the mousewheel as one.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: A better approach would be to check the differences of the scrollTops detected but i don't have time to implement that right now.

Comment: Set .hiddenScroll filter to filter: opacity(1); so you can see whats happening